# Mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

What I want to do is,create a table in mysql by passing the table name as a parameter in the stored procedure.I'm using following code for stored procedure in mysql.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE createtable(IN tablename varchar(20))
BEGIN
   SET @s=CONCAT('CREATE TABLE', tablename, '(month varchar(20))');
   PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
   EXECUTE stmt;
END //
```

and when i call it

```
CALL createtable('account');
```

I get the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the MySQL server version for the right syntax to us...

I don't know where I'm wrong..

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the spaces before and after your table name. Try

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE createtable(IN tablename varchar(20))
BEGIN
    SET @s=CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', tablename, ' (month varchar(20))');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END //
```